# mysql group by date(day) not showing if no result in specific day

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is the query I have

```
select sender, count(*) as Total, date_format(senttime, '%m - %Y - %d') as Sent_Date 
from sendmail sm 
left join subuser su 
   on (sm.sender = su.sub_user) 
where senttime <= NOW() 
  AND senttime >= DATE_SUB(senttime, INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
group by date_format(senttime, '%d'), sender
```

Here is the actual output

[image]

It is showing only two dates `21` and `22` but I need 7 dates with total count 0.

How can I do this.

Comment: While the screenshot of your output is helpful, what might be more helpful is sample data and desired output, preferably just listed in question or put into sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 0):

Well if there is no sent time, it doesn't satisfy your `where` condition.

```
where senttime <= NOW() 
AND senttime >= DATE_SUB(senttime, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

You need to add an `or` to it:

```
where senttime IS NULL OR (senttime <= NOW() 
AND senttime >= DATE_SUB(senttime, INTERVAL 7 DAY))
```

And you may need to switch this

```
from sendmail sm 
left join subuser su
```

to

```
from subuser su 
left join sendmail sm
```

assuming sendmail only has values when something has been sent - you need to select from the one you know will be there, and then left join the one that you're not sure of (or do a different type of join)

Comment: Great opportunity to use a `RIGHT JOIN` just passed you by.

Comment: hence the "or do a different type of join" comment - but I think in terms of left joins, so never really do right joins.

Comment: I don't blame you, most everyone neglects the poor `RIGHT JOIN`